# node.js calling child_process.fork reports 'Error: listen EADDRINUSE'

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-7-x64

when the 'child_process.fork( './driver' ,' runs over , an error occurs :

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1156:14)
    at listen (net.js:1182:10)
    at Agent.Server.listen (net.js:1267:5)
    at Object.start (_debugger_agent.js:20:9)
    at startup (node.js:86:9)
    at node.js:814:3
```

And the log doesn't print its log , so ,the child process does not run ,right?  How to debug this problem , I am using windows 7 .

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like exactly what the error is telling: that executing `./driver` causes something to attempt to use a port on your machine that is already in use. Without more details it's hard to help.

Comment: I have comment  the code in the ./driver , still report the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running on Visual Studio.

The error clearly Says Debugger Port is already in use.

If you change to any other port say 9999 (as below) or any other free port before forking it should work fine.

process.execArgv = ["--debug=9999"];